# Is there any way to run for loop for decimal number in php?

Tags: php, html, for-loop

I need to display select box with decimal numbers by using php FOR loop. See below code:

```
<select name="animationDelayTime">
    <option value="0.1">0.1s</option>
    <option value="0.2">0.2s</option>
    <option value="0.3">0.3s</option>
    <option value="0.4">0.4s</option>
    <option value="0.5">0.5s</option>
    <option value="0.6">0.6s</option>
    <option value="0.7">0.7s</option>
    <option value="0.8">0.8s</option>
    <option value="0.9">0.9s</option>
    <option value="1.0">1.0s</option>
    <option value="1.1">1.1s</option>
    <option value="1.2">1.2s</option>
    <option value="1.3">1.3s</option>
</select>
```

This loop would continue until it reach at number 10.

Is it possible to loop decimal numbers in php ?

> If possible can anyone check following code that is not working. I
>   fetch data from database and I used conditional statement for
>   selecting and show existing record selected in select box:
>
> ```
> <select class="form-control" name="delayTime" title="Choose animation delay time..." data-toggle="tooltip" required>
> <?php
>  for ($x = 0.1; $x <= 10.1; $x=$x+0.1) {
>   if($x == $updateEntry->delayTime){
>    echo '<option value="' .$x.'" selected>'.$x.'s</option>';
>   }
>    echo '<option value="' .$x.'">'.$x.'s</option>'.PHP_EOL;
>  }
> ?>
> </select>
> ```
>
> **Please see below screen shot. The value 7.1 should be selected in the select box but it not selected only beginning two or three number get selected, don't know why? Please help me to sort it.**
>   [image: The value 7.1 should be selected in the select box but it not selected only beginning two or three number get selected, don't know why? Please help me to sort it.]

**Finally I found the method to solve this issue by using range in foreach loop. See below:**

```
<?php
 foreach (range(0.1, 10, 0.1) as $val) {
   $selected = ($val == $updateEntry->delayTime) ? "selected": "";
    echo '<option value="' . $val . '" '.$selected.'>' . $val . 's</option>';
 }
?>
```

Comment: For such a question, you should share what you've tried and what exactly is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by many ways. For example using a `for()` loop. Start with `0.1`, go till it is `10` and increment on every step by `0.1`

`range()` is also a good choice for this but then you've to use `foreach()`

```
<?php
  echo '<select name="animationDelayTime">';
  for ($x = 0.1; $x <= 10; $x=$x+0.1) {
   echo '<option value="' .$x.'">'.$x.'s</option>'.PHP_EOL;
  }
  echo '</select>';  
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/RlAcM

**EDIT:**  AS per new requirement change. Here I just assume the value of `$updateEntry->delayTime` is **0.5**. You can use it as you're getting it from DB.

```
<select class="form-control" name="delayTime" title="Choose animation delay time..." data-toggle="tooltip" required>
<?php
 //$selected = '';
 for ($x = 0.1; $x <= 10.1; $x=$x+0.1) {
   $selected = ($x == 0.5) ? "selected": "";     
   echo '<option value="' .$x.'" '.$selected.'>'.$x.'s</option>'.PHP_EOL;
 }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Can you please check my question again, I'm getting a very strange issue.

Comment: @PawanMall I just assume the value of `$updateEntry->delayTime` is **0.5**  then it is working as expected and for 0.5 the option is **selected**  See demo https://3v4l.org/iLRIW You just need to do some tweak. Also I've edited my answer as per your new requirement. Let me know is that you want or not?

Comment: I check your code but getting same issue If i change the value, https://3v4l.org/6CqbW

Comment: Please check my question again where I attached screen shot of my program.

Comment: Finally I resolve the issue by using range in foreach loop and thanks for all your support. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

Simple with [`range`](http://php.net/range):

```
// first `0.1` - start value, `10` - end value, second `0.1` - step
foreach (range(0.1, 10, 0.1) as $val) {  
    echo '<option value="' . $val . '">' . $val . 's</option>';
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy for all your help. I got what I want to do.

Comment: I found this answer to be better. I do not know why but when I set my values using the accepted answer as `($x = 89.0; $x <= 108.0; $x=$x+0.1)` I got many lines echoing correctly but several returning as "94.89999999999" etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use While loop:

```
// Initialize the variable
$val = 0.1; 

// Loop until the value is less than or equal to 10
while ($val <= 10) {  

    // generate the string using $val
    echo '<option value="' . $val . '">' . $val . 's</option>';

    // Increment the value by 0.1 for next iteration
    $val += 0.1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
For( $x = 0 ; $x < 1.4; $x += 0.1){

echo "<option value='$x'>".$x."s</option>";
}
```

Comment: Incrementing by 0.1